# how to add label, TextInput in kivy python

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, textinput

I am a beginner in python especially in kivy. I am facing some small issues in designing a GUI. As per the diagram(I have attached) in the page, I am unable to put label, TextInput in proper format. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelItem
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

Builder.load_string("""

<Test>:
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'page1'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'label'
            Label:
                text: 'entry'       
            TextInput:
                text: 'Entry'
            TextInput:
                text: 'Entry'
            CheckBox: 
                text: 'CheckBox'
            Button:
                text: 'button'


    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'page2'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'label'
            TextInput:
                text: 'entry'
            Label:
                text: 'label'
            TextInput:
                text: 'entry'
            Button:
                text: 'button'

""")

class Test(TabbedPanel):
    pass

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        test = Test()
        panel = TabbedPanelItem()
        test.add_widget(panel)
        return test

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Try using [GridLayouts](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html) instead of BoxLayout. Hint: for page 2 with 5 child widgets, add an empty 6th widget to help with spacing.

Comment: Dear @Mox , Can you solve this ? I have tried a lot, it's not coming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are putting your widgets (Label, TextInput, CheckBox, Button...) in a BoxLayout, the behaviour of BoxLayout is to group widgets into a (only one) column or row, you can change the orientation of the BoxLayout setting the attr 'orientation', by default 'horizontal'. ([read this](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html?highlight=boxlayout#module-kivy.uix.boxlayout))

You can put one BoxLayout into other BoxLayout, and setting the orientation you can create diferent things, for you page1 you can do something like this:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Label:
            text: 'label'
        TextInput:
            text: 'Entry'
        CheckBox: 
            text: 'CheckBox'
        Button:
            text: 'button'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Label:
            text: 'label'
        TextInput:
            text: 'Entry'
        CheckBox: 
            text: 'CheckBox'
        Button:
            text: 'button'
```

Like **Mox** said in comments, maybe [GridLayout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html) works fine for your app.

If you are beginner in kivy I recommend you watch [this videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdNh1e1kmiPP4YApJm8ENK2yMlwF1_edq) from Alexander Taylor, one of the core developers of kivy.

Comment: dear, @favcau it's not working . It's showing error " TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' ". Can you please check the full code what you have given? I tried GridLayout , but the same error is coming. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @crazyDelight, my code is an example, is just a piece of kv language. You need to add my example in your code, do something [like this](http://linkode.org/#OzzvQPYAzoa41Ml8HSiQ41). My example hasn't error, maybe you paste it in a wrong place, I need to see your code for solve the error you had, try to debug it your self.